# location updates service isn't working when app is moved to background

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using the below app code to recieve locations updates from the GPS every second and print an output to the log. This works fine for me as long as the app is in foreground, but the updates stop when it is moved to background until it is being brought back to foreground.

I have these permissions at the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.android.hardware.location.gps"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is the service class

```
public class GoogleService extends Service implements LocationListener {

boolean isGPSEnable = false;
boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
double latitude, longitude;
LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Timer mTimer = null;
long notify_interval = 1000;
public static String str_receiver = "servicetutorial.service.receiver";
Intent intent;


public GoogleService() {

}
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(), 5, notify_interval);
    intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
    fn_getlocation();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

private void fn_getlocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable) {

    } else {

        if (isNetworkEnable) {
            location = null;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {

                    Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                    Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");

                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    fn_update(location);
                }
            }

        }


        if (isGPSEnable) {
            location = null;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                    Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    fn_update(location);
                }
            }
        }


    }

}

private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fn_getlocation();
            }
        });

    }
}

private void fn_update(Location location) {

    intent.putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
    intent.putExtra("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
 }
}
```

TimerTaskToGetLocation works correctly.This is Logcat in foreground.

```
 2021-08-21 02:29:42.400 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_longitude:135.22084902
 2021-08-21 02:29:43.416 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_latitude:34.8317199
 2021-08-21 02:29:43.416 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_longitude:135.2209639
 2021-08-21 02:29:43.431 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_latitude:34.83170759
 2021-08-21 02:29:43.431 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_longitude:135.22084902
```

This is Logcat in background.

```
2021-08-21 02:30:28.748 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_latitude:34.83170759
2021-08-21 02:30:28.749 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_longitude:135.22084902
2021-08-21 02:30:28.766 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_latitude:34.83170759
2021-08-21 02:30:28.766 8904-8904/com.websarva.wings.android.notification4 E/get_longitude:135.22084902
```

What else needs to be done for this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider starting service as foreground and showing notification for such service or use WorkManager.
Official Google's recommendation if following:

"If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on running background services when the app itself isn't in the foreground. In most situations, for example, you shouldn't access location information from the background. Instead, schedule tasks using WorkManager."
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

You can find examples on pages like https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/
I've check this approach and it works for your case.

Regarding WorkManager you can also use https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: Thanks! I try it!